# Only administrator account can run scheduled tasks

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, task-scheduler

I am running Windows 2008 Server and I have set up a scheduled task that executes a SQL script from the command prompt. The script and command work completely fine.

I set this scheduled task to run once a day, under the Administrator user account and it has been working fine for over a week. I now want to disable the Administrator account and run the scheduled task as another user (with exactly the same privileges i.e. `Users`, `Administrators`).

When I change the user for the scheduled task and try to run it. The Task Scheduler tells me that the task has run (Last run result: 0x0) but the script has not been executed.

**Scheduled Task information**

- Run whether user is logged in or not (true)
- Run with highest privileges (true)

**tl;dr**
Changing an already working scheduled task running under `Administrator` to another user account stops the scheduled task working (user has same role/privileges).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that even though the user had Administrator privileges on the Windows Server it did not have `sysadmin` or `dbo` privileges on the SQL server DB/instance. By giving my user these privileges on SQL Server the script executed.